# Any examples of how a worker status can be changed via text in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I'm currently working on setting up a call center for our group, with the idea being that any calls in our queue would be routed to appropriate individuals cell phones to answer.

I am struggling on how to give our support staff the ability to change their worker status via a text message, with the following workflow:

- User texts a number, with a specific answer prompting change ("Active", "Offline", etc...)
- Based on number coming from, makes change to workers status.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TaskRouter (which appears to be the case), it looks like you can use the below API call to set worker status (activity_sid).

[Update a Worker Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/worker#update-a-worker-resource)

[Code Example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/worker?code-sample=code-update-worker&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)